# SwiftUI - How do I read a string array out of a Identifiable struct

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I am trying to loop through the string array that I created in my Identifiable Struct. I can read a single record of the array but when I put it in a foreach loop, I can't loop through all the records. Basically I want to show all the assets that the selected person has. The Foreach in the DetailView Struct is the problem. Please see image and code below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Person :Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var assets: [String]
}

extension Person {

    static func all() -> [Person] {

        return [
            Person(name: "John", assets: ["Car1", "Car2"]),
            Person(name: "Peter", assets: ["House1", "Car3"])
        ]
    }
}

var persons = Person.all()

struct DetailView: View {
    var person1: Person

    var body: some View {

        List{
            Text("NAME")
                .bold()
            Text(person1.name)

            Text("ASSETS")
                .bold()
            ForEach(person1) {asset in
                Text(person1.assets[asset1])
            }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(person1.name))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(persons) {person in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(person1: person)) {
                        Text(person.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle("Person assets")
        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try this

```
import SwiftUI

struct Asset : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var text : String

    init(_ text : String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

struct Person :Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var assets: [Asset]
}

extension Person {

    static func all() -> [Person] {

        return [
            Person(name: "John", assets: [Asset("Car1"), Asset("Car2")]),
            Person(name: "Peter", assets: [Asset("House1"), Asset("Car3")])
        ]
    }
}

var persons = Person.all()

struct DetailView: View {
    var person1: Person

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Text("NAME")
                .bold()
            Text(person1.name)

            Text("ASSETS")
                .bold()
            List (person1.assets, id: \.self) { asset in

                Text(asset.text)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(person1.name))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(persons) {person in
                    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(person1: person)) {
                        Text(person.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Person assets")
            .border(Color.black, width: 1)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a code only answer and needs improvement, please explain what has been changed and how it solves the issue

Comment: Awesome, Thank you. This got me on the right path. By using List, it only returned  the first record, but when I changed it to ForEach, it returned all records. I also had to remove .text from Text(asset,text). The final code looks like this -                  ForEach (person1.assets, id: \.self) { asset in                Text(asset)
                }

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: looks like Jadon has another opinion about my answer as you have... ;)

Comment: That is not the point, answers are not only meant for OP but also for other people who might be searching for a solution to a similar problem as the one OP asked about and for them or any other future reader of this answer it would be very helpful with some textual context to easier understand the answer.

Comment: @Chris This might be interesting to read and could explain downvotes on this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290233/1288408